# Powershell test-path not working?

Tags: powershell, testing, path

Wow. I must be on the stupid pills today. I'm using a simple Test-Path in a script and I cannot figure out why it doesn't enter the IF block when the file **is** present. I run the same code in the ISE command window and it works fine:

```
$allfile="c:\users\rs02130\desktop\sonarRules\jsrulesall.xlsx"
Write-Output "Testing $allfile"
if (Test-Path $allfile) 
{
    Write-Output "In If"
    try
    {
        Write-Output "Removing $allfile"
        Remove-Item $allfile -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Removed $allfile"
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error "Error removing $allfile"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental but I don't get it. The full original script has similar code in another region and it works fine.

Comment: Double check the file name, especially since you indicate similar code works fine.

Comment: What result does `Get-Item $allfile` yield?

Comment: If I run Get-Item $allfile inside the script it errors with "Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\RS02130\Desktop\SonarRules\jsrulesall.xlsx' because it does not exist." If I run it outside the script it runs fine. The file is definitely there. I did a Copy as Path from Windows Explorer and pasted the path directly into the script...

Comment: Huh. I stuck a "Get-ChildItem *.xlsx" in the script and it doesn't show the file. I look in Explorer or run the same command in PS> and it's there. Go figure. A security thing? On my own desktop?

Comment: Now it is showing up in the Get-ChildItem but the Test-Path is still failing...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. A combination of a bad file wildcard further up that was deleting the file before I got to it further down and the asynchronous nature of Get-ChildItem vs. Write-Host that caused me to think the file was there when it wasn't.